# How did they make it look like Agent Sloan from Section 31 was disintegrated in front of the Romulan council?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-transporter, romulan, section-31

DS9 "Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges":

> NERAL: It is the finding of this Committee that Senator Cretak has
>   conspired to commit treason against the State. Sentence to be
>   determined at a later date. Doctor Bashir will be returned to the
>   Bellerophon. Mister Sloan is remanded to the custody of the Tal'Shiar
>   for further interrogation.
>
> SLOAN: No!
>
> (Sloan grabs a weapon from his guard, and **Koval vapourises him.**)

When I first watched the episode I though perhaps Sloan had a double but the Admiral ruled that out. A little later in the episode:

> BASHIR: But he's alive, isn't he?
>
> ROSS: **He was supposed to be beamed away a split second before the
>   phaser beam hit him. Whether it worked or not, I couldn't say.**
>
> BASHIR: How long has Koval been working for Starfleet?

We have a confirmation that Sloan is clearly alive. A little later:

> (Bashir wakes to see -)
>
> **SLOAN: Good evening.**
>
> BASHIR: Are you expecting applause? Have you come to take a bow?
>
> SLOAN: I just wanted to say thank you.

So Sloan is clearly alive.

I just watched the episode. I saw him disintegrate. If he got hit before he was transported out he'd be dead. I saw the image of him disintegrate from the disruptor blast.

I understand that the Admiral says that he was beamed out but wasn't sure if it worked. IF he beamed out before the blast, we would have seem a beam out, as well as the blast hitting the wall behind him.

I was really confused and had to go back and re-read the transcripts.

Anybody have any idea how they pulled this off exactly and make it look like he was disintegrated by the disruptor without actually being there, if that's what happened?

Answer (score 6):

There are numerous ways in which this could be accomplished. Off the top of my head, the most obvious way would be using the transporter to *switch* Sloan with a duplicate slab of flesh grown out of his own DNA.

Failing that, we've seen other times in which a transporter beam has been mistaken for someone being vapourised by a phaser blast, notably in [TNG: Gambit](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kJOaAQ2zkc0J:www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/256.txt%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).

> **PICARD:** *These mercenaries use weapons which activate their Transporter. It allows them to beam away objects quickly, by simply
>   firing at them. That's what they did to me.*

Comment: And many other shows have used the same trick in universe.

Comment: +1 That's a good answer I didn't think of that. They must have transported something in because it was clearly a humanoid outline that disintegrated. Any idea why we didn't see a transporter beam at the same time? Almost every race that uses transporter technology has some sort of signature  beam that encoumpases the object being transported. If the Federation had technology to mask it you'd think they'd implement it on all of their transporters.

Comment: @Richard sorry in my comment/question above I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @JMFB - High power transporter beams work much faster. I presume they're not used regularly as they're likely lethal to the user.